# CSS style of FormLayout

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Is there a way to style the margin between two elements:

[image]

It would like to change the margin to "var(--lumo-space-s)"

It would be great to do it directly within the source by getStyle().set(..., ...).

Thanks for your help

Best Regards,
Thomas

Comment: Have you tried to define the value of the `--vaadin-form-layout-column-spacing` in `getStyle().set("--vaadin-form-layout-column-spacing",value)`?

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks for the help! It is working perfect! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define the value of the `--vaadin-form-layout-column-spacing` in

```
getStyle().set("--vaadin-form-layout-column-spacing",value);
```

Comment: Also struggling with spacing between form fields. The `--vaadin-form-layout-column-spacing` did not solve it for me though.
Default the form displays all fields in 2 columns. With this style added some fields in the 2nd column move to the 1st column. But other fields just stay with no spacing between the fields.
Found this [form layout styling demo](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-form-layout/1.0.0/demo/styling.html) but the `--vaadin-form-layout-column-gap` mentioned there does nothing.

Comment: Looking at the source code of [vaadin-form-layout.js](https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/blob/main/packages/form-layout/src/vaadin-form-layout.js) it looks not possible to add spacing. On L504 and L514 a margin with `0px` is added. There seems no way to change this with configuration.